# NIS translation files

Tags: server, translation

I've found a problem in NIS translation to Portuguese (pt-pt). I've searched everywere and couldn't find where can I fix it (there's not Launchpad).

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to have `pt`, I see currently `de` the only one available beside `en`.

- Launchpad source package: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nis
- Debian package tracker: https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/nis
- Upstream project site: http://www.linux-nis.org/

  1. Check upstream site, Send an email to maintainer, telling him that you are going to translate it to `pt`. (I couldn't find any upstream source repository, he may point you to it).
  2. Either through source repository cloning or downloading last release source archive, copy `.pot` files, rename them to `pt.po` then translate them.
  3. Send him back the translated ones.

It will take a while before translations land to Debian then Ubuntu and any other distribution.